# setting countourf levels but still have full color range

Tags: python

I'm working on a program for displaying different simulation Parameters.
One Parameter for example is Efficiency where I want to focus on the range from 85-100%.
With my Code the plot uses green and red although I set the colormap to jet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzxYe.png)

It should look more or less like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6QiN.png)

```
scaleforbar = np.linspace(minval, maxval,10)
   
levels_bar = (scaleforbar)   
digits='%1.0f'
if Data2plot == 'Efficiency [%]':
    levels_bar = [0,0.85,0.9,0.92,0.93,0.94,0.95,0.96,0.97,0.98,0.99,]
    digits = '%1.2f'  
                                                             # Generates different Levels for the colorbar
cp = plt.contourf(speed1,torque1,data1,levels=levels_bar, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap='jet', alpha=0.8)     # plotting the data 
plt.plot(rpmforMaxTorqueList,maxTorqueMList,label='Max Torque Motor' )                                 # plotting the max Torque curve for Motor
plt.plot(rpmforMaxTorqueList,maxTorqueGList, label='Max Torque Generator')                            # plotting the max Torque curve for Generator
plt.legend(loc ='lower right')  
                                                                    # placing legend in the lower right corner
plt.clabel(cp , inline=False, fontsize=10, fmt=digits,colors='black',linewidths=1)
plt.ylabel('Torque [Nm]')                                               # Adding label to y axis
plt.xlabel('Speed [rpm]')                                               # Adding label to x acis

plt.title(sheet)                                                       # adding Titel to Diagramm

cbar = plt.colorbar()                                                   # Adding colorbar to diagramm to see what values and colors match
cbar.set_label(Data2plot)                                               # Adding label to colorbar to see what value is given


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got a workaround for myself

Getting as many colours in a List out of the colormap as I have levels and then telling the contourf function to use the colours from the List and not the cmap.

```
 scaleforbar = np.linspace(minval, maxval,10)
levels_bar = (scaleforbar)   
digits='%1.0f'
col = None
colmap = 'jet'
if Data2plot == 'Efficiency [%]':
   cmap = mlp.cm.get_cmap('jet')
   levels_bar =[0,0.85,0.9,0.91,0.92,0.93, 0.94,0.95, 0.96]
   digits='%1.2f'
   coln=np.linspace(minval,maxval,len(levels_bar))
   col=[]
   for i in coln:
        col.append(cmap(i))   
   
   colmap =None

                                                             # Generates different Levels for the colorbar
cp = plt.contourf(speed1,torque1,data1,levels=levels_bar, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap=colmap, alpha=0.8,colors=col)     # plotting the data 
plt.plot(rpmforMaxTorqueList,maxTorqueMList,label='Max Torque Motor' )                                 # plotting the max Torque curve for Motor
plt.plot(rpmforMaxTorqueList,maxTorqueGList, label='Max Torque Generator')                            # plotting the max Torque curve for Generator
plt.legend(loc ='lower right')  
                                                                    # placing legend in the lower right corner
plt.clabel(cp , inline=False, fontsize=10, fmt=digits,colors='black',linewidths=1)
plt.ylabel('Torque [Nm]')                                               # Adding label to y axis
plt.xlabel('Speed [rpm]')                                               # Adding label to x acis

plt.title(sheet)                                                       # adding Titel to Diagramm


cbar = plt.colorbar()                                                   # Adding colorbar to diagramm to see what values and colors match
cbar.set_label(Data2plot)                                               # Adding label to colorbar to see what value is given


plt.show()
```